# Variables id() in Python

Tags: python

I have a question about the variables id() in python:

```
a=[2,3]
b=a
print b
>>>[2, 3]

a.remove(2)
print b
>>>[3]
```

This is because id(a) == id(b)?; how can I avoid this? I need to define  b  in another way?

Answer (score 0):

You can slice it, so you get a copy of the first list:

```
b= a[:]
```